# how can I download a pdf file from my browser that allows browsing only(read only)

Tags: pdf

My question is how can I download a pdf file from my browser that allows browsing only(read only) and does not allow downloading or printing as shown in the attached picture.
I think this pdf file can be downloaded through (php) could help me one specializes in php and Site Script?
please see the picture 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VNop.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Reecm.jpg)

/downloads/MTIyNTUtMTIucGRm.html

This is the link for pdf
http://185.62.36.66:812/web/viewer.html?file=%2Fdownloads%2FMjEwLTEucGRm.html#textLayer=off

There is no download button and no printing
Is there anyone who can upload it to me?

Comment: This is the link for pdf
http://185.62.36.66:812/web/viewer.html?file=%2Fdownloads%2FMjEwLTEucGRm.html#textLayer=off

There is no download button and no printing
Is there anyone who can upload it to me?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is somewhere in properties of program where do you edit pdf file or right-click on that file and hit properties, and check Read-Only. Then upload the Read-Only applied file to web.

Comment: This is the link for pdf
http://185.62.36.66:812/web/viewer.html?file=%2Fdownloads%2FMjEwLTEucGRm.html#textLayer=off

There is no download button and no printing
Is there anyone who can upload it to me?